# Mysql query to with multiple entires with status

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-columns

We have a table where order_id is multiple occurrences based on the status set to it example

```
+-------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| id    | order_id   | status          | created_at          |
+-------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 32621 | 0000000881 | AUTHORISED      | 2018-08-06 16:17:38 |
| 32622 | 0000000881 | AUTHORISED      | 2018-08-06 16:46:29 |
| 32623 | 0000000881 | REFUSED         | 2018-08-06 17:18:33 |
| 32624 | 0000000881 | CAPTURED        | 2018-08-06 17:54:10 |
| 32625 | 0000000881 | CAPTURED        | 2018-08-06 18:33:47 |
| 32626 | 0000000882 | REFUSED         | 2018-08-06 19:17:44 |
| 32627 | 0000000882 | AUTHORISED      | 2018-08-06 20:06:25 |
| 32628 | 0000000882 | CAPTURED        | 2018-08-06 21:00:13 |
| 32629 | 0000000883 | REFUSED         | 2018-08-06 21:59:48 |
| 32630 | 0000000883 | CAPTURED        | 2018-08-06 23:05:40 |
```

We are currently finding the order_id which doesn't have an Authorised status set.

Any suggestion can be appreciated as We are low on these queries.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do aggregation :

```
SELECT order_id
FROM table t
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING SUM(status = 'AUTHORISED') = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause to find `order_id` values where `AUTHORISED` does not exist.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 order_id
FROM yourTable AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
  SELECT 1
  FROM yourTable AS t2
  WHERE t.order_id = t2.order_id
    AND t2.status = 'AUTHORISED'
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a clause to find `order_id` values where `AUTHORISED` does not exist.

```
SELECT order_id
FROM table t
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING SUM(status = 'AUTHORISED') = 0;
```